# Spark dataframe filter and select, why their locations does not matter?

Tags: apache-spark

Given a spark dataframe `df`, I found that `df.filter(col("label")===1).select("user")` equals `df.select("user").filter(col("label")===1)`.

Could anyone tell me the reason that the location of `filter` does not matter? Why the second expression does not throw exception?

spark version is 2.3.4, scala version is 2.11.8

Comment: Interesting question... Maybe due to optimizations in execution plans? Possible that filter is being done first in both cases.

Comment: This is because the Optimized query plan will be same in both of the case. You can check with explain(true) in both case.

Comment: @koiralo @ernest_k Thank you! I check with explain(true) and found that they both do `filter` firstly then do `select` in the physical plan.